# Referencing columns with quotes in the column names in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have columns named like this. I get

```
["year_of_birth"]   
["month_of_birth"]  
["day_of_birth"]    
["birth_datetime"]
```

When I write

```
Select ["year_of_birth"]    from dbo.table_name
```

I get this error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'care_site_id'.

Is there any way I can reference column names with double quotes in my SQL script? Is there any way to programmatically rename these column names?

Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
     ["year_of_birth"] [varchar](50) NULL,
     ["month_of_birth"] [varchar](50) NULL,
     ["day_of_birth"] [varchar](50) NULL,
     ["birth_datetime"] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Do you really have quotes in your column names?

Comment: Could you please show a `Create Table` for at least one of your tables where this happens? And BTW: The error doesn't match to your select statement

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. This works: `DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
["year_of_birth"] VARCHAR(20),
["month_of_birth"] VARCHAR(20),
["day_of_birth"] VARCHAR(20),
["birth_datetime"] VARCHAR(20)
);` then `SELECT ["year_of_birth"] FROM @t;` returns an empty result set with no error.

Comment: Looks like you `SELECT` the `care_site_id` column without `"`.

Comment: @jch double quotes are used the same way as square brackets - to quote table and column names. I suspect you though the double quotes were part of the name

Comment: There is no column `care_site_id`!

Comment: I very much doubt that the SQL `Select ["year_of_birth"]    from dbo.table_name` generates the error *"Invalid column name 'care_site_id'."* That statement and error have nothing to with with each other (unless `dbo.table_name` is really a `VIEW` and is referencing the column `care_site_id`; which doesn't exist). Post the full SQL you are running, as well as the `CREATE` statement for your table **in your original question**.

Comment: Please post the results of the following query: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table_name'` replacing `'table_name'` with your actual table name in quotes.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing things that are **obviously**  numeric (like day, month and year of birth) in `varchar(50)` columns?? **Use the most appropriate** datatype - ***ALWAYS*** - and this would be `INT` or `SMALLINT` here - but certainly not a string type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a procedure to fix the column names:

```
create procedure FixColumnNames @tableName sysname, @schemaName sysname = 'dbo'
as
begin

  begin transaction
  declare c cursor local for
  select c.name
  from sys.columns c
  join sys.objects o
    on c.object_id = o.object_id
  where o.name = @tableName
    and o.schema_id = schema_id(@schemaName)
    and c.name like '%"%'

  declare @cn sysname
  open c;
  fetch next from c into @cn;
  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin
    declare @old nvarchar(2000) = quotename(@schemaName) + '.' + quotename(@tableName) + '.' + quotename(@cn);
    declare @new sysname = replace(@cn,'"','');
    print 'renaming ' + @old +' to ' + @new;
    exec sp_rename @old,@new,'COLUMN';
    fetch next from c into @cn;
  end
  close c;
  deallocate c;
  commit transaction;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can rename table columns using the **sp_rename** stored procedure. Here's some documentation: [SP_RENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Usually it's not a best practice to have column names like the ones you have.

If you want to do it programmatically, this at using SMO (SqlManagementObjects) library from MS, [which offers a rich API for Data Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017)